# An incredibile endgame

Tags: analysis, endgame, computer-chess

Is the following position

```
[FEN "8/P1R5/K3p3/4k3/B3b3/8/8/1r6 w - - 0 1"]
```

a win ( for White) or a draw? The position above is derived from a variation of Stockfish vs Komodo TCEC Season 19 Division Premier.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to note:

1 refer to "on" a square, not in

2: An image would still be highly appreciated as compared to writing out coordinates.

Assuming I have the right position
[image]

White has a higher chance of winning according to engines.
However, if assuming both engines play perfect moves, this by human trial will be a draw. I can't see anyway how white could possibly promote the pawn, and if the bishop sacks for the a7 pawn there is almost no way an engine would not get a draw in this position. Rook + bishop against Rook is a draw.

Answer (score 0):

Basically put... if black defends a8 square it's a draw... and he can.